# Using polymorphism to print out string occurrences

Tags: java

I having trouble figuring out how to print out how many times "Dr" titles appear in my array objects in my tester program as they contain more than one string. Is using the equals class the best way to approach this?

Note: I am using inheritance and polymorphism.

```
public class Driver {

public static void main(String[ ] args) {
    Person[] persons = new Person[5];

    persons[0] = new Person("John Smith");
    persons[1] = new Person();
    persons[2] = new TitledPerson("Rowan Bean", "Mr");
    persons[3] = new TitledPerson("Phil McGraw", "Dr");
    persons[4] = new TitledPerson("Hugo Strange", "Dr");

    System.out.println("Person 3 and 4 are equal: " + persons[2].equals(persons[3]));
    System.out.println();

    String search = "Dr";
    int counter = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < persons.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(persons[i]); 

        if(persons[i] instanceof TitledPerson) {
            if(persons[i].equals(search)) {
            counter++;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println();

System.out.println("There are " + counter + " 'Dr' titles listed.");
}   
}
```

Person Class:

```
public class Person {

private String name;
private final static String DEFAULT_NAME = "N/A";

public Person() {
    this(DEFAULT_NAME);
}

public Person(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public String toString() {
    return "Name: " + name;
}

public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if(obj instanceof Person) {
        Person otherPerson = (Person) obj;
        return name.equalsIgnoreCase(otherPerson.getName());
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

}
```

TitledPerson Class:

```
public class TitledPerson extends Person { 

private String title;

public TitledPerson() {
}

public TitledPerson(String name, String title) {
    super(name);
    this.title = title;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    String parentString = super.toString();
    parentString += ", " + title;
    return parentString;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if(obj instanceof TitledPerson) {
        TitledPerson otherPers = (TitledPerson) obj;
        return super.equals(obj) && this.title.equalsIgnoreCase(otherPers.title);                               
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

}
```

Comment: `persons[i].equals(search)` can never be true because `persons[i]` is a `Person` and `search` is a `String`. One should never equal the other.

Comment: Please provide `Person` and `TitledPerson` classes.

Comment: @PWC I edited my other classes into my questions!

Answer (score 1):

Change to using `getTitle` from your `TitledPerson` class while comparing with the `search` keyword.

```
if(((TitledPerson)persons[i]).getTitle().equals(search)) {
        counter++;      
}
```

Comment: That'll throw a `ClassCastException` when it's `Person`.

Comment: @Jeremy the OP already has a `if(persons[i] instanceof TitledPerson)`, so shouldn't get into such case.

Comment: Oh, I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

The `equals` method in `TitledPerson` calls super class `equals` which will cause the name and title must be the same for equality.

I think the correct implementation of `equals` in `TitledPerson` should be

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if(obj instanceof TitledPerson) {
        TitledPerson otherPers = (TitledPerson) obj;
        return this.title.equalsIgnoreCase(otherPers.title);                               
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you seem to do this :

```
  if(persons[i] instanceof TitledPerson) {
        if(persons[i].equals(search)) {
        counter++;
        }
```

person is object with a name and a title 
search on the other hand, is a string 
so you need to do this :

```
 if(persons[i] instanceof TitledPerson) {
        if(persons[i].title.equals(search)) {
        counter++;
        }
```